# different extent after extract by mask

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, extract-by-mask

I have two rasters and a study area vector, they are all WGS84 CRS. When I use the vector to mask those rasters, the results showed different extents and rows and columns.
I tried 'extract by mask' in R(terra::mask),ArcGIS Pro, QGIS, ArcMap.

I summarized the results(rows and columns) in this table.

[image]

I don't know how to upload test data on StackExchange. But the rasterA(2017) and rasterB(2018) are from the same datasets ——"http://data.tpdc.ac.cn/zh-hans/data/faae7605-a0f2-4d18-b28f-5cee413766a2/"

But there is a tiny difference. The result extent of 2018,2019,2020 are different with 2017 and before.

Comment: I guess different implementations behave differently with pixels that are partially masked. Without test data it is hard to say anything about the difference between A and B with the same software. Do rasterA and rasterB have the same pixel size and origin?

Comment: I don't know how to upload test data on this. But the rasterA and rasterB are from the same datasets "http://data.tpdc.ac.cn/zh-hans/data/faae7605-a0f2-4d18-b28f-5cee413766a2/"